# How to configure Spring Security with Pretty Faces?

Tags: spring-security, prettyfaces

The title of the question speaks for itself.

I want both to secure home.xhtml and the clean URL /Home.

In spring security config, do i need to do what follows or is there another way of doing it ?

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home.xhtml" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/Home" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>
```

Thanks

**UPDATE :**

Actually my solution is to be careful with files and url names.I do this in spring security file to be more coherent:

```
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/Home*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

That secures the two URL...all url in fact beginning by Home (not case sensitive)